# When I switch from \bibliographystyle{plainnat} to \bibliographystyle{apalike} the citation in the text switch from authoryear to numbered

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apa-style, apacite

I want the bibliography in APA style as follow:

> "Charnes, A., Cooper, W. W., and Rhodes, E. (1978). Measuring the efficiency of decision making units. European journal of operational research, 2(6):429–444."

while the citation within the text as follow:

> "... decisional making units” (Charnes et al., 1978)."

However, when  in the preamble I change from:

```
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\nobibliography*
```

to:

```
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\nobibliography*
```

the citation within the text turns to:

> "... decisional making units” (1)."

ADDITIONAL INFO:

- In `thesis.tex`:

  ```
  \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,authoryear,print,index]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{spacing}{0.9}
  \bibliographystyle{apalike}
  \cleardoublepage
  \bibliography{References/references}
  \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={References}]
  \end{spacing}
  \end{document}
  ```

  Where `reference` is the folder used to upload `file.bibtex` as:

  ```
   @article{charnes1978measuring,
    title={Measuring the efficiency of decision making units},
    author={Charnes, Abraham and Cooper, William W and Rhodes, Edwardo},
    journal={European journal of operational research},
    volume={2},
    number={6},
    pages={429--444},
    year={1978},
    publisher={Elsevier}
  }
  ```
- In `preable.tex`

  ```
  \usepackage{bibentry}
  \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
  \nobibliography*
  ```

  where `plainnat` in `\bibliographystyle` I use to change with `apelike`.
- I cite as follow:

  ```
  ... decisional making units” \citep{charnes1978measuring}.
  ```

Could please someone help me to get the wanted citation style?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Please let me know if I need to make it more clear. I apologize, I am not an expert in this field. I recently started to use LaTeX.

I am using a template in Overleaf. I did not created it for scratch.

Many thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please add a short compilable TeX code building your bibliography to your question? Please do not forget to add the used bib entry too.

Comment: If you want full APA style you are better off using `apacite` or `biblatex-apa`. `apalike` is really only like APA and does not satisfy the list of demands of the real APA style.

Comment: It might help to do something like `\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}`. But as Kurt points out, it's hard to tell without you posting a MWE

Comment: That said, I can not reproduce the output you describe with only the three lines shown in the question. I suggest you show us a complete example document starting with `\documentclass` that includes the relevant bits of the preamble and an example citation in `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Please include a `.bib` entry as well. This would make for a so-called MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864. An MWE is often the quickest way to a good answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments!! I updated the information. Please let me know if additional information are required. Thank you very much!

Comment: https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template

Comment: **(1)** Do you have to use the template you are using and `PhDThesisPSnPDF.cls`? The template is quite massive and can easily overwhelm you, especially if you are new to LaTeX. It may also be quite tricky to understand and then change its behaviour. My suggestion is to start with one of the standard document classes and build up your preamble gradually if and when you need new stuff. That helps keep the code cleaner and understandable. Often there are multiple versions of templates like this out in the wild and it can be a pain to find out which version you use and which solutions you need.

Comment: **(2)** You seem to mix classic BibTeX and `biblatex`. (A bit of background is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864.) The version of the class found on GitHub https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template either loads `biblatex`, `natbib` or no package. Your code has `\printbibliography`, which is a  `biblatex` command. But then you also have `\bibliographystyle`, which is a BibTeX command. You also issue `\bibliography` in the document, which can only be done with BibTeX. The package `bibentry` is also normally associated with BibTeX.

Comment: My advice would be to throw away the template and to get started with the bibliography using a really minimal setup like the one in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864.

Comment: Thank you very much to everyone!! Your comments are teaching me a lot! I appreciate the suggestion to start with another easier model. However, I have written around 150 pages of my thesis in this template and I would like to keep it. Do you think it is not possible to get the desired citation style  within this template?

Comment: It should be overall straightforward if a bit time consuming to migrate your 150 pages from this template to a more minimal set-up (of course there might be the odd tricky bit you come across, but overall it should be possible). Due to the sheer size of the template it is already quite a bit more complicated than necessary to help you, but if you insist on continuing to use the template, you may want to add links to the exact version of the files you are using to your question.

Comment: Thank you moewe! I would prefer to keep this template, not because of the time required to move the pages to a new one, but because I won't be able to make a nice layout as the one I'm using and I have only one week time. I created two GitHub files with the thesis.tex and the preamble.tex.  
https://github.com/Giorgio22/Giorgio-s-Thesis/commit/641089da131c98d23266e0c1065ecd0379f365bb 
https://github.com/Giorgio22/Giorgio-s-Thesis/commit/3a2c714cf1049aa03e9646281432a343be854e6a    
and the link of the template version I am using
https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/releases/tag/v2.4

Comment: Do you want real APA style as defined in the *Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association* or do you just want something that is like APA ('`apalike`'), i.e. a style that has author-year citations and a matching bibliography?

Comment: I would something like this http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~rlenth/ALPHA/apa-tutorial.pdf
I do not know why in my case References are listed Name, Surname, Title, Journal, Year instead of --> Surname, Initial name, (year), Title, etc. 
Thanks a lot @moewe!!!

Comment: I created a pull request with the necessary changes at https://github.com/Giorgio22/Giorgio-s-Thesis/pull/1. With these files dropped onto https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/releases/tag/v2.4 the document compiles and the result are `apalike` citations/bibliography.

Comment: thank you very much @moewe, it very appreciated your help. 
I have tried to make the changes as you suggested, also by simply using only %\usepackage{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}
%\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={((},close={))}}
but, even though the list of references appear in APA style, the citations within the text appears with the number, instead of authoryear.
I tried to make your changes in another document and it worked well as I want. But it does not work for my thesis. I think I will print two pdf and then I merge them. Thank you very very much anyhow!!!!

Comment: That's one of the main reasons why I advise against using those templates. They get far too unwieldy far too quickly and then it can be extremely hard to figure out where the issue lies. Good luck with your thesis!

Comment: I will keep in mind your tips from now on!! Thanks really a lot!@moewe